# Sort the values of your array and reverse it

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this:

The output is as below:

[image]

I want to sort the image output from right to left
Does anyone know the solution?

Thanks

Comment: you haven't specified an array

Comment: Not sure what exactly you need, but take a look at PHP function `array_reverse` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php ) and other array functions

Comment: I have updated your answer to display an image, but you need to update your question to include your array code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) to sort the array in ascending order (0 to 30). To reverse all the elements of the sorted array you can use [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php):

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];
sort($arr);
$arr = array_reverse($arr);
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/8Sa3sh

You can also use [`rsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) to sort directly in descending order:

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];
rsort($arr);
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/pi33zK